# partition data into chunks and then assure thread safety

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library, plinq

i'm writing some code that basically receive data from socket, perform deserialization and then passed to my application.the deserialized objects can be grouped by their id's (the id is being generated during the deserialization process).

to increase the performance of my application i wanted to use the new parallelism capabilities that came with C# 4.0. the only constraint i have is that 2 threads cannot access object with the same id's. now i know that i can just perform lock() on a sync object that will be placed inside the object but i want to avoid these locks (performance is an issue here).

The design I've thought about:

1. create some kind of partitioner that will split data by the ID (this will make sure that every buffer i'll get will always have the same object id's group together).
2. assign thread by using TPL of PLINQ

can someone suggest me some sources that do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest `PLINQ` when developing for multiple processors or cores.

> PLINQ is a query execution engine that accepts any LINQ-to-Objects or LINQ-to-XML query and automatically utilizes multiple processors or cores for execution when they are available. The change in programming model is tiny, meaning you don't need to be a concurrency guru to use it. In fact, threads and locks won't even come up unless you really want to dive under the hood to understand how it all works. PLINQ is a key component of Parallel FX, the next generation of concurrency support in the Microsoft® .NET Framework.

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163329.aspx) covers:

- From LINQ to PLINQ
- PLINQ Programming Model
- Processing Query Output
- Concurrent Exceptions
- Ordering in the Output Results
- Side Effects
- Putting PLINQ to Work

[Parallel LINQ (PLINQ)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460688.aspx)

Comment: i totally agree that PLINQ is a good start but the question is: if i have 2 threads that handle list of object (right after deserialization- notice that buffer keeps arriving and these messages keep floating in my system) with some property (that's the id property) and now i need to partition it (by ids) and forward it to the thread (using as parallel method) in my application. how can i assure that each item with the same id will be sent to a thread that wont required locking?

Comment: @Tzahi Sounds like you need to look at [`ConcurrentQueue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265.aspx). Alternatively if the incoming objects is really concurrent with processing (and potentially never ending) then perhaps the [Reactive Extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh242985(VS.103).aspx) might be a better place to start.

Comment: concurrentQueue is not good enough since this gets me back to the current solution i have- where everything is pushed to queue and thread handles all the data. this is causing bottlenecks in my systems and very low CPU utilization on the other hand. I'm checking the reactive extensions solution - it looks promising... keep u posted very soon.

Comment: reaction extensions is very intresting in deed, it's seems like the solution for me. thanks Richard!